# mysql import is not working

Tags: mysql, import, mysql-error-1064

I want to import data into mysql, but getting the following error.

```
error 1064 :parsing error
```

I have created database with name `test`, user is `test` and password is `test`.
but not able to import.

Command I tried :-

```
mysql>mysql-u test -p test test > 'c:/Users/test.sql';
```

Comment: Check whether the username and password are correct mysql-u test -p test test > 'c:/Users/test.sql';

Answer (score 4):

You should do something like this -

```
mysql mysql-u test -ptest test < 'c:/Users/test.sql'
```

1. password: change -p test with -ptest
2. SQL scipt:  change > with <

[mysql — The MySQL Command-Line Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html)

Answer (score 3):

Symbol '>' is used for export not for import. For import you need to use '<'

Use following command:

For import:

```
 >mysql -u username -p  databasename  < path/test.sql
```

For export:

```
 >mysqldump -u username -p databasename tableName > path/test.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

From a security perspective down the line I wouldn't include the password in command-line executions as it can be stored in the command history.  To this end I'd recommend the following

```
// no quotes
mysql -u test -p test < c:/Users/test.sql;

// with quotes (i.e. directory name has spaces)
mysql -u test -p test < "c:/Users/test.sql";
```

Here you are specifying

```
mysql                    // mysql command
-u test                  // user mysql
-p                       // with a password
test                     // schema name
< c:/Users/test.sql      // Redirects the content of test.sql into mysql.  File name should not be quoted with single quotes
```

After that command you will then be prompted for a password.

The alternative is as mentioned by the other answer here to specify `-ptest` as you have no space between the `-p` and your password when using the `-pYourPasswordHere` logic in that way, however as I mentioned this will then put your password into the command history (more applicable for linux machines, but still a good thing to not get into the habit of doing)

Comment: Please can you specify the exact command you are using, and the exact error you are getting?  As an additional note, you shouldn't quote the file name with single quotes.  If you need to quote the path in Windows you should use double-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Syntax is

```
mysql <dbname> -u <username> -p<password> -e source <backup_file.sql>
```

Command

```
mysql test -u test -ptest -e source "c:/Users/test.sql"
```